# Issue with Bootstrap icon

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am having some issue with my Bootstrap setting. I am learning bootstrap. i was trying to design a buttong with bootstrap. i want to add some icon on the buttton but i couldnt get it work. i tried lots of tutorials and even with given example on the bootstrap page... Can any one help me to find my faults?? Thanks in advance. :)

here is my code:

```
{% load static %}
```

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hey!!!, {{user.username}}</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registration</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">My Account</a>
              </li>


          </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container bordere" >








<div class="mt-2">
    <a href="{% url 'authuser' %}"> <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Add Items</button></a> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>View Details</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Download Report</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Email Report</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Create Bill</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Modify Data</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
       </button>

</div>


            <div class="row mb-2 mt-2">
                <div class="col-2 bordere miniheight">
                    clo 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-10 bordere">
                    clo 2
                </div>




            </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body>
```

here is the example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
            Delete<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
           </button>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output of sample code: [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keg1d.png)
My code Output: [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9pa3.png)

Solution:
According to Mr.  Komninos i was looking a wrong documentation. it was true. i solved it with fontawesome icons and its now working..

Working Code:

```
{% load static %}
```

```
</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hey!!!, {{user.username}}</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registration</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">My Account</a>
              </li>


          </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container bordere" >








<div class="mt-2">
    <a href="{% url 'authuser' %}"> <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Add Items</button></a> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit"><i class="fas fa-1x fa-search"> </i> View Details</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Download Report</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Email Report</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Create Bill</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Modify Data</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
       </button>

</div>


            <div class="row mb-2 mt-2">
                <div class="col-2 bordere miniheight">
                    clo 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-10 bordere">
                    clo 2
                </div>




            </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Working output: [image: Click Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyphicons were removed in Bootstrap 4. You were probably looking at the v3 documentation. [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#components)

You can find the same icons [here](https://www.glyphicons.com/) or use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

Comment: Yes.. You are right. I have solved it with fontawesome. Thank you so much.... i have attached the working output along with the question. :)